# Swift closure capture and inout variables

Tags: swift

Consider the following code:

```
func foo(inout success: Bool) -> (()->()) {
    return { _ in
        success = true
        print (success)
    }
}

var success = false
let closure = foo(&success)

closure()          //prints "true"
print(success)     //prints "false"
```

The closure appears to be creating a copy of success and does not change the original. Why is this taking place? I had assumed that the closure would point to the original because we are passing an `inout` variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It makes sense that this wouldn't update your `success` variable because your `inout` parameter is a parameter of `foo`, not of the closure itself. You get the desired behavior if you make the `inout` parameter a parameter of the closure:

```
var success = false
let closure = { (inout flag: Bool) -> () in
    flag = true
    print(flag)
}

closure(&success)  //prints "true"
print(success)     //prints "true"
```

This pattern also works with the function, too, as long as you keep the `inout` parameter a parameter of the closure:

```
func foo() -> ((inout Bool)->()) {
    return { flag in
        flag = true
        print (flag)
    }
}

var success = false
let closure = foo()

closure(&success)  //prints "true"
print(success)     //prints "true"
```

You also get the desired behavior if you use a reference type:

```
class BooleanClass: CustomStringConvertible {
    var value: Bool

    init(value: Bool) {
        self.value = value
    }

    var description: String { return "\(value)" }
}

func foo(flag: BooleanClass) -> (()->()) {
    return {
        flag.value = true
        print (flag)
    }
}

let success = BooleanClass(value: false)
let closure = foo(success)

closure()          //prints "true"
print(success)     //prints "true"
```

Comment: What if the closure is part of a framework and therefore we cannot change its arguments to accommodate an inout variable?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be covered by [Swift Evolution proposal 0035](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0035-limit-inout-capture.md), and is considered a bug.

The document there refers to the `inout` parameter to the function as "a **shadow copy** that is written back to the argument when the callee returns". This seems to mean that there is, in essence, a temporary variable named `success` in the executing context of `foo()`. The value of that temp is then put into the outer `success` only when `foo()` returns.

Since in your `foo()`, the closure has not run when `foo()` returns, the value of the "shadow copy" has not changed. The outer `success` keeps its value.

The important part is that the closure **has captured the *shadow copy***, not the outer `success` as you expect. So when the closure finally runs, that variable's value does change, but it no longer has any connection to the original outer `success`.

The proposal uses this snippet to demonstrate:

> ```
> func captureAndEscape(inout x: Int) -> () -> Void {
>   let closure = { x += 1 }
>   closure()
>   return closure
> }
>
> var x = 22
> let closure = captureAndEscape(&x)
> print(x) // => 23
> closure()
> print("still \(x)") // => still 23
> ```

Comment: Why shadow copy? Is it shallow copy ?

Comment: "Shadow" in the sense of being hidden.